# Instagram API only return few results

Tags: instagram-api

I need to display a timeline on 4 websites, with the last 6 posts of the instagram account link to the website.

The api link `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/userid/media/recent?&access_token=token&count=6` was working until one or two days.
Now, i have sometimes one result, sometimes 2 or 3, and i don't understand why.

I have the same problem with the public access : `https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1`

Do you have any idea ?
Many thanks!